# What is "instrument contamination"?

Tags: terminology, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

When going through instrumental variable literature sometimes, but rather rarely, I happen to find expression "*instrument contamination*".

- What does it mean? Is this another expression for endogeneity?
- Are there different aspects or meanings of it?
- Is this expression connected to some fields, or rather general?

Basic and more advanced literature is always welcome.

---

Example:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1098301511015373

Comment: Can you link/cite an example?

Comment: I added an example of what I found. But this is a bit too advanced for me. I am searching for an explanation starting from basics or defining it with possibly reliable source.

Comment: That paper seems to define contamination as $\rho(z,\varepsilon)$, which is the correlation of the instruments with the (unobservable) error term in the outcome equation. This seems like garden-variety endogeneity.

Comment: The question is why use different terms (is there a reason?), and where did they take this from? Some econometric books, articles?

Comment: [Pleiotropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiotropy).